# replace goto inside a macro with something else

Tags: c++, macros, constexpr, goto

I'm attempting to remove goto statement inside [Mach7](https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7/blob/master/code/mach7/match.hpp#L753), because [goto is not allowed in constexpr function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266577/why-disallow-goto-in-constexpr-functions):

```
#define MatchQ(s) {                                                            \
        XTL_MATCH_PREAMBULA(s)                                                 \
        enum { __base_counter = XTL_COUNTER };                                 \
        typedef mch::unified_switch<source_type> switch_traits;                \
        XTL_PRELOADABLE_LOCAL_STATIC(XTL_CPP0X_TYPENAME switch_traits::static_data_type,static_data,match_uid_type,XTL_EMPTY()); \
        XTL_CPP0X_TYPENAME switch_traits::local_data_type  local_data;         \
        bool processed = false;                                       \
        size_t jump_target = switch_traits::choose(subject_ptr,static_data,local_data); \
        XTL_CONCAT(ReMatch,__LINE__):                                          \
        switch (jump_target)                                                   \
        {                                                                      \
            XTL_NON_REDUNDANCY_ONLY(default:)                                  \
            { XTL_REDUNDANCY_ONLY(try){{                                       \
            if (switch_traits::on_default(jump_target,local_data,static_data)) \
                goto XTL_CONCAT(ReMatch,__LINE__);                             \
            XTL_SUBCLAUSE_FIRST
```

The codes above use goto here: `goto XTL_CONCAT(ReMatch,__LINE__);`, which is possible to jump to upside of switch statement.

How to replace goto here with something else?

Comment: Might enclosing the lines starting from XTL_CONCAT(ReMatch,__LINE__): all the way till the end of the closing bracket of switch with "while(true){", and then replacing "goto" statements with "break/continue" be a solution?

Comment: @ozlsn I have tried it before posting this question, but failed somehow, lemme gcc -E to dig into it.

Comment: XTL_REDUNDANCY_ONLY may set up another loop which a "continue;" would cycle through. We'd have to see all the macros.

Comment: Why do you use such complex macro's? Can't you use regular functions instead?

Comment: @JVApen I'm not the author of this pattern-matching library. So I cannot answer this question before get familiar enough with this library

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @ozlsn and `gcc -E`, the replacement is done. 
persuade codes:

```
while(true)
{
    bool continue_flag = false;
    switch(var)
    {
        default:
            if(something)
                continue_flag = true;
                break;
        // do something
        OtherCases:
            // do something
    }
    if (!contine_flag)
        break;
}
```

full commit here: https://github.com/FirstLoveLife/Mach7/commit/3db24a337a7643018ed9e12ac95f53f9a036251c

Here is a related QA: [Using continue in a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146763/using-continue-in-a-switch-statement)